# How can I call a LWC when a button is click?

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal

I have a lightning quick action lwc (Aura with child lwc), which I need is when a button is clicked another lwc will be shown. Just like in standard lead conversion when the convert button is clicked this page is shown.

[image]

Comment: There's isn't a way to 'Call' a component. What you want to do is to have a parent component which switches from your Lead conversion component to the Lead conversion success component (as shown above)

Answer (score 1):

There is trick to show the new component and hide the current component. by using the template tag.

Put both LWC component in the aura component as child render the component based on aura is true. and hide the another component on button click.